# Get Next and Previous Elements in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array, with non-sequential IDs, that looks something like this:

```
PhotoList[89725] = new Array();
PhotoList[89725]['ImageID'] = '89725';
PhotoList[89725]['ImageSize'] = '123';
PhotoList[89726] = new Array();
PhotoList[89726]['ImageID'] = '89726';
PhotoList[89726]['ImageSize'] = '234';
PhotoList[89727] = new Array();
PhotoList[89727]['ImageID'] = '89727';
PhotoList[89727]['ImageSize'] = '345';
Etc....
```

I'm trying to figure out, given an ID, how can I can get the next and previous ID... So that I could do something like this:

```
<div id="current">Showing You ID: 89726 Size: 234</div>
Get Prev Get Next
```

Obviously, if we're at the end or beginning of the array we just a message...

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you add properties 'Prev' & 'Next' to that array?

```
PhotoList[89725] = new Array();
PhotoList[89725]['Prev'] = 89724;
PhotoList[89725]['Next'] = 89726;
PhotoList[89725]['ImageID'] = '89725';
PhotoList[89725]['ImageSize'] = '123';
```

This is just 'doubly-linked list' data structure.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your example the IDs are sequential...
This is another way of writing your example.  new Array() really isn't what you should be using because those are objects you are creating.  Also, I left the numbers as strings, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that.  You could add next and prev like kuy suggested

```
PhotoList[89725] = {ImageID: '89725',
                    ImageSize: '123'};
PhotoList[89725] = {ImageID: '89726',
                    ImageSize: '234',
                    Next: '89727',
                    Prev: '89725'};
PhotoList[89725] = {ImageID: '89727',
                    ImageSize: '345'};
```

All of these are accessible just like your other structure.

Comment: I'll second Jerry.  Forget about the arrays.  PhotoList should be an object as well.  var PhotoList = { 89725: { ImageID: 89725, ImageSize: 123, next: 89726}, 89725: {} etc...

Answer (score 3):

There's really no way other than to iterate through the possible ids sequentially until you find one which has an entry in your array.  For example:

```
function findClosest(arr, id, increasing) {
    var step = increasing ? 1 : -1;
    for(var i=id+step; i>=0 && i<=max_id; i+=step)
        if( arr[id] )
            return id;
}
```

Obviously, this approach requires that you keep track of the max_id so that you don't iterate forever; here I assume that it's a global variable, but you might want to make it a parameter to the `findClosest` function.  You'd call this function like so:

```
var prev = findClosest(arr, id, false);
var next = findClosest(arr, id, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the rest quotes you should be using objects not an array. Also make sure you create new arrays using the literal notation and not the new keyword with built in types. The new keyword is bad news and you could clobber the global object. Check out JSLint.

```
var a = new Array(); //bad dont use
var a = []; //this is the best way to create a new array
var o = {}; //create new objects like this
```

As for the problem at hand. Why not write a simple container that has its own internal counter?

```
function PhotoListContainer(PhotoList)
{
    if(PhotoList === undefined)
        throw("no photo list");

    this.counter = 0;
    var self = this;

    this.current = function(){
         return PhotoList[self.counter];
    };

    this.next = function(){
        return PhotoList[self.counter + 1];
    };

    this.prev = function(){
        return PhotoList[self.counter - 1];
    };

    // You could even write a function that loops each value from the current counter :)
    this.each_from_counter = function(callback){
        for(var i = self.counter; i < PhotoList.length; i++)
        {
             callback(PhotoList[i], i);
             self.counter++;
        }        
    };

}

//use 

var pc = new PhotoListContainer(PhotoList);
pc.counter = 500;
pc.next(); //returns the 501st object
pc.prev(); //returns the 499th object
pc.each_from_counter(function(photo, index){
     photo.somehting;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sibNum = 0;
var sibList = [];
var prevSiblingID = false;
for (n in w) {
   sibNum++;
   sibList[n] = {
      title : n,
      prevSiblingID : prevSiblingID
   };
       if (prevSiblingID) {
          sibList[prevSiblingID].nextSiblingID = n;
   }
   prevSiblingID = n;
};
sibList[prevSiblingID].nextSiblingID = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

No arrays at all are better..

```
images = {
    0: {
        size: 12345, /* dont realy need as you can use JS to mesure the size. */
        title: "day 1 on holiday"
    },
    1: {
        size: 13549, /* dont realy need as you can use JS to mesure the size. */
        title: "day 2 on holiday"
    },
    2: {
        size: 16548, /* dont realy need as you can use JS to mesure the size. */
        title: "day 3 on holiday"
    },
}

for(x in images){
    /* x = "the id of the image." */
    url[] = "/images/" + x + ".png";
    title[] = images[x].title;
    size[] = images[x].size;
    console.log("File: " + url[x] + " , Title: " + title[x] + " , Size: " + size + "bytes")
}
```

Comment: Although true, this doesn't help answer the question; op has specified that they want to calculate what the prev and next ID's are, given a known key, where the other keys are not necessarily sequential.

Comment: What's the thinking here? Your indexing an object with numbers starting with zero. How is this better than using an array?

Answer (score -1):

you can use grep function and calculate prev or next item of specified array:

```
object = $.grep(data, function(e) {
            if(e.id == yourId) {
                return data[data.indexOf(e) + 1]; // or -1 for prev item
            }
     });
```

Answer (score -3):

i think your image list will come from DB so you may can try this code, this code is working for me.

```
<?
    $prev="";
    $next="";
    $cur=0;
    $i=0;
    $pid=$_GET['pid'];
    while($rowcon=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {       
        $arr[$i]=$rowcon['pid'];
        if($rowcon['pid']==$pid)
        {
            $cur=$i;
        }
        $i++;
    }   
    if($cur<$num_rows)
        $next=$arr[$cur+1];
    else
        $next="";
    if($cur>0)
        $prev=$arr[$cur-1];
    else
        $prev="";
    echo $prev."   ".$cur."   ".$next;
?>
```

Comment: the question is about javascript not php