# get prev and next items in array

Tags: jquery

i have an array of numbers

```
var projects = [ 645,629,648 ];
```

and a number 645

i need to get the next(629) and prev(648) numbers?

can i do it with jquery?

Comment: maybe help :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058185/get-next-and-previous-elements-in-javascript-array

Comment: Have you mixed your numbers up? 648 isn't the previous number in that array. And what is worng with using a for loop, then taking the number on each side of the index when you find the desired number?

Comment: @slugster - yes it *is* the previous number when the array is circular!

Comment: He's most likely looking for a method to do this with a selector of some sort.

Comment: @eyalb - then you should say that in your description. Don't expect us to be mind readers, and lots of us have learnt not to make assumptions about things - i have never encountered a situation where an array was circular. Be explicit and accurate :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can make it a bit shorter overall using jquery's [`$.inArray()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) with a modulus:

```
var p = [ 645,629,648 ];
var start = 645;
var next = p[($.inArray(start, p) + 1) % p.length];
var prev = p[($.inArray(start, p) - 1 + p.length) % p.length];
```

Or, function based:

```
function nextProject(num) { 
  return p[($.inArray(num, p) + 1) % p.length]; 
}
function prevProject(num) { 
  return p[($.inArray(num, p) - 1 + p.length) % p.length];
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using `$.inArray()` compared to `indexOf()`, I cannot see any different behavior when looking at the provided documentation? (Just curious as I'd like to learn new things)

Comment: @Veger - I guess since some browsers didn't support `indexOf` at some point (I'm not sure which), it'll use it internally if present, otherwise it'll loop and find it.

Comment: almost what i wanted, except the behavior is wrong, if i choose last element and let it check for LAST, it goes to first in the array.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about jQuery, but it is fairly simple to create something on your own (assuming that you have always unique numbers in your  array):

```
var projects = [ 645,629,648 ];

function next(number)
{
    var index = projects.indexOf(number);
    index++;
    if(index >= projects.length)
        index = 0;

    return projects[index];
}
```

Calling `next()` with a project number returns the next project number. Something very similar can be made for the `prev()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to sort the array once afterwards you can just use the code starting from `//start`

If number is not present nothing is output

```
var projects = [ 645, 629, 648 ], number = 645, i = -1;
projects.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a > b ? 1 : -1;
});
//start
i = projects.indexOf(number);
if(i > 0)
    alert(projects[i-1]);
if(i < (projects.length - 1) && i >= 0)
    alert(projects[i+1]);
```