# Cycling through jQuery object to get previous/next values using only a key?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, key, cycle

Finding this very tricky. All I have to work with is a grade number--[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] which I'm using as the key--and from that I must generate 1 previous and 1 next link. Here's what I've produced so far:

```
var grUrl = {
    '-1': '/preschool_fun.html',
    '0': '/kindergarten_activities.html',
    '1': '/first_grade_stuff.html',
    '2': '/second_grade_education.html',
    '3': '/third_grade_crafts.html',
    '4': '/fourth_grade_numbers.html',
    '5': '/fifth_grade_reading.html'
};

  function prevGrade(num) {
    return grUrl[($.inArray(num, grUrl) - 1 + grUrl.length) % grUrl.length];
  }
  function nextGrade(num) {
    return grUrl[($.inArray(num, grUrl) + 1) % grUrl.length];
  }

$(document).on('click', 'a.leftarr', function() {
    var gradeNum = $(this).attr('data-grade');
    var prevLink = prevGrade(gradeNum);
    window.location = prevLink;
    return false;
});
```

Then I'd do the inverse for the nextLink var. Trouble is, I don't know how to:

1. Get the value of the previous/next object values from a key
2. Ensure that the previous link cycles back from grade 5 down
3. Ensure that the next link cycles up from preschool up

(Yes, the prev/next functions here were suggested for standard arrays, not objects--is there a similar approach with objects?)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that in trying to economize by using a jQuery object, I'm creating more problems than simply using a more straightforward albeit more verbose solution. The answer I found was to use two arrays (based on: ['get prev and next items in array'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498415/get-prev-and-next-items-in-array)):

```
  var grPos = [
  '-1',
  '0',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5'
  ];

  var grUrl = [
  '/preschool_crafts.htm',
  '/kindergarten_games.htm',
  '/first_grade_letters.htm',
  '/second_grade_numbers.htm',
  '/third_grade_activities.htm',
  '/fourth_grade_trips.htm',
  '/fifth_grade_reading.htm'
  ];

  $(document).on('click', 'a.leftarr', function(){
    window.location = grUrl[($.inArray($(this).attr('data-grade'), grPos) - 1 + grPos.length) % grPos.length];
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'a.rightarr', function(){
    window.location = grUrl[($.inArray($(this).attr('data-grade'), grPos) + 1) % grPos.length];
    return false;
  });
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful.