# Sum next array elements from a starting position (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need this for dynamically use.
I have 2 associated arrays:

```
Var $some = [1, 2, 3];
Var $other = [a, b, c];
```

a, b, c are some html ids and 1, 2, 3 are their values. 
I want something like this on trigger:

```
$'#a').attr('max', //b+c val(2+3)
$'#b').attr('max', //a+c val(1+3)
$'#c').attr('max', //a+b val(1+2)
```

I ve searched here [get prev and next items in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498415/get-prev-and-next-items-in-array) about finding next elements in array, and I think would be usefull a loop that itinerate elements a (then b then c) with its values and for each one execute a code like: sum next elements to them. Substracting element value after sumed won't work pripperly because I want that script on some ranges change...
So...my question would be: how can I sum elements itinerated from a loop? I think that would be the key to solve this because I can loop it 2 times in this example and would stop without started element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `some` and `other` are equal, so you can try this solution.

```js
const some = [1, 2, 3];
const other = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

other.forEach((item, index) => {
   const sum = some.reduce((s, c, i) => index !== i ? s += c : s, 0);
   
   $(`#${item}`).text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
```

I am iterating over each item in the `other` array. The functions passed into the [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) gets two parameters - the current item and it's index in the `other` array. Then I call [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the `some` array and pass a function into it which gets three parameters - the `accumulate value`, the current item and it's index in the `some` array. In the body I check if the `some` current item index is not equal to the `other` current item index ( this prevent for `a` to add the value for `a` ) so I add it to the `s`, which contains the result in each iteration of `some.reduce`a return it which is done automatically in one line statement if not return the result without adding the current item value.

You can write the reduce function like this to be more readable

```
some.reduce((s, c, i) =>  {
   if(index !== i) {
      s += c; 
   }

   return s;
}, 0)
```

Comment: I will have a look to understand your code...foreach will run for every item, and index is what for?

Comment: @Florin also you need to add it in the `max` attibute, I put it in the `html` to show the result

Comment: Something interesing here... In the documentation gave me an idea on the point with initial value. Inserting initial value gets the value from where to start suming...is there any function that makes what reduce make but substracting values(gave in array) from an initial value ? Like in my initial question "-" instead of +? Sorry if is dumb quest

Comment: Just pass what value you want to be initial and use `-` sign

Comment: Yeah, I realised that later... If I add more html elements, in order to make it works, I can add more letters in parameters and along the functions?(sorry, I trying to understand how really parameters works)

Comment: Yes, add how many. Just be sure that you have also added their values

Comment: Omg omg, works like charm!!! No need to add letters in reduce parameters, just added some elements in var some and var other...but how? I can t understand parameters...You said to computer that we have a b c values and to insert in a= b+c, b=a+c, etc...but how the computer know that if I add one more element to treat it too like others? As I said...I am hard understanding parameters...in that function a b c is not same with s c i, but s c i are models of what should be happen with a b c (d e f ...more)?

Comment: I was about `other` and `some`. It iterates over all elements in array. It will be better to read about `reduce` function

Comment: After some hair lost, I got it...you are magic!  So l, starting with index 0 and s(acumulator) 0, reduce will run 1 time for each array value(3 times). s+= c : s are conditions in that 3 runs. At first index will be like: 1)s=s(return 0), 2)s=s+c(0+current val =2), 3)s=s+c(2+3). So I can have control over that runs of reduce playng with parameters, Got it? :D

Comment: Yes, you got :)

Comment: Sir, thanks you so much for your help! Is not about code, but about made me understand. I have one more curiosity, but I don t want to open new topic because i am affraid it could be dumb... How can I sum/reduce a multidim array arr=[ [1,3,5], [2,4,1],[1,2,3]] to get something like this arr=[4,9,9] (sum first sub-indexes from all sub-arrays then second, then third with shorter code?([1+2+1, 3+4+2, 5,1,3]).Considering i can have like 10 sub-arrays...just a refference please...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that key of `other` is the same with it's corresponding value on `some`

```js
const some = [1, 2, 3];
const other = [a, b, c];

$.each(other, function(key, value){                        // Loop thru each id
    var sum = some.reduce((x, y) => x + y) - some[key]; // add each 'some' elements and subtracting the id's value
    $(value).attr('max', sum);                             // set max attr of id equal to sum
});

// log output on console
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="a">
<input type="number" id="b">
<input type="number" id="c">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `html(function)` to do the loop indexing and a `reduce()` for sum

```js
var some = [1, 2, 3];
var other = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('#'+ other.join(',#')).html((elIdx)=>{
    return some.reduce((a,c,i) => a+= (i===elIdx ? 0 : c), 0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous solutions works nice, of course, but, just in case, here is more straightforward solution:

```
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<$(this).siblings().length;i++) {
sum+= parseInt($( this ).siblings().eq(i).val());
}
console.log(sum);
$(this).attr('max',sum)
});
```

```js
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) { // loop through each input
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<$(this).siblings().length;i++) { // get all siblings
sum+= parseInt($( this ).siblings().eq(i).val()); //calculate sum of siblings values
}
console.log(sum);
$(this).attr('max',sum)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inputs">
<input type="number" id="a" value=1>
<input type="number" id="b" value=2>
<input type="number" id="c" value=3>
</div>
```

Comment: I will consider your solutions too, because what I ve asked and what all of you answered me is not the solve of my plan, is just a way to start from. Ty! I find your solution more dynamically for what I am propose to do